# make str.contains more explicit

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a cell in a data frame that contains the word "`Scan`". Unfortunately, there is also a word "`Scan-Steuerung`" which I would like to ignore.
How can I do this in python?

Is it also possible to get the index of this cell?

I'm looking for a cell in a data frame that contains the word "`Scan`". Unfortunately, there is also a word "`Scan-Steuerung`" which I would like to ignore.
How can I do this in python?

Is it also possible to get the index of this cell?

edit: I think it would be sufficient when I can read these two lines separately. At the moment, I use:

```
line = df[df["Name:"].str.contains("Scan")]
```

and when I print, I receive both lines at once.

Comment: What is "think test"?

Comment: So you need `line = df.index[df["Name:"].str.contains(r"\bScan\b")]` ?

Comment: Thank you! I guess I can use this as a workaround!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regex pattern boundaries `\b`

**Ex:**

```
df["Col"].str.contains(r"\bScan\b")
```

Comment: Thank you! What is the return of that command?