# How to explicitly find string using str.contains() in a loop?

Tags: python, regex, string

I am searching particular strings in first column using `str.contain()` in a big file. There are some cases are reported even if they partially match with the provided string. For example:

My file structure:

```
miRNA,Gene,Species_ID,PCT
miR-17-5p/331-5p,AAK1,9606,0.94
miR-17-5p/31-5p,Gnp,9606,0.92
miR-17-5p/130-5p,AAK1,9606,0.94
miR-17-5p/30-5p,Gnp,9606,0.94
```

when I run my code search

```
DE_miRNAs = ['31-5p', '150-3p'] #the actual list is much bigger
for miRNA in DE_miRNAs:
    targets = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
    new_df = targets.loc[targets['miRNA'].str.contains(miRNA)]
```

I am expecting to only get only the second raw:

```
miR-17-5p/31-5p,Gnp,9606,0.92
```

but I de get both first and second raw - 331-5p come in the result too which should not:

```
miR-17-5p/331-5p,AAK1,9606,0.94
miR-17-5p/31-5p,Gnp,9606,0.92
```

Is there a way to make the `str.contains()` more specific? There is a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56592828/make-str-contains-more-explicit) but how I can implement it to a for loop? `str.contains(r"\bmiRNA\b")` does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, do you have to use Pandas here? I have an impression all you need is to read a CSV file and only take the lines where the `DE_miRNAs` match as a whole word. Right? Or do you want to say `Series.str.contains()` instead of `str.contains()`?

Comment: Yes exactly but after having the rows ( there can be several rows for a pattern because Gene column can be different) I need to have the top 200 based on ascending PCT column.

Comment: Does https://ideone.com/l4fqjL help?

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.contains` with a regex alternation which is surrounded by word boundaries on both sides:

```py
DE_miRNAs = ['31-5p', '150-3p']
regex = r'\b(' + '|'.join(DE_miRNAs) + r')\b'

targets = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
new_df = targets.loc[targets['miRNA'].str.contains(regex)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`contains` is a function that takes a regex pattern as an argument. You should be more explicit about the regex pattern you are using.

In your case, I suggest you use `/31-5p` instead of `31-5p`:

```py
DE_miRNAs = ['31-5p', '150-3p'] #the actual list is much bigger
for miRNA in DE_miRNAs:
    targets = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
    new_df = targets.loc[targets['miRNA'].str.contains("/" + miRNA)]
```